# Error sending postMessage from iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I want to send a message to the parent window like this:

```js
window.parent.postMessage({type: 'gg', data: '0'}, '*');
```

But the parent window isn't receiving anything in the useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
      console.log("fsfsfs");
      if (event.data.type === 'toolInfo') {
        const receivedValue = event.data.value;
        console.log(receivedValue); // This will log 'someValue'
        // Do something with the received value
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
    };
  }, []);
```

it is not printing anything. Right now I'm testing at localhost, so the iframe has 127.0.0.1:9001 and the parent has 127.0.0.1:3000.

Comment: Try including the URL to the parent e.g., `postMessage(..., "http://127.0.0.1:3000")`. Are you sure you are not removing the event listener too soon?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I've already tried that approach and it shows me this error:
`faililed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin`

Comment: Should work. Are you testing on Chrome or Chromium browsers? That's how I post from a `chrome-extension:` protocol to any arbitrary Web page https://github.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio/blob/master/native_messaging/capture_system_audio/background_transferable.js#L113-L146, https://github.com/guest271314/captureSystemAudio/blob/master/native_messaging/capture_system_audio/transferableStream.js#L31-L59. Notice how I include the origin in the `name` of the `iframe` at `this.transferableWindow.name = location.href;` and retrieve that name in the iframe `parent.postMessage(1, name);`.

Comment: @guest271314 I fixed it, i just needed to change from parent.postMessage to top.postMessage